# Working out a specific charge of an atom?

Tags: mass, charge

I know how this formula work if the mass of the nucleus and the charge of the nucleus is given, however I do not understand how they get them as I have two books which do it differently.

So the specific charge is calculated by: charge / mass

> #### Textbook 1: Example 1:
>
> A nucleus of Hydrogen has 1 proton and no neutrons. It has a charge of $1.60\times 10^{-19}\:\mathrm{C}$ and it has a mass of $1.67\times 10^{-27}\:\mathrm{kg}$. Specific charge is $9.58\times 10^{7} \:\mathrm{C \:kg^{-1}}$.
>
> #### Textbook 1 Example 2:
>
> An ion of the magnesium isotope has a 12 protons and 12 neutrons. It has a charge of $3.2\times 10^{-19}\:\mathrm{C}$ and it has a mass of $3.98\times 10^{-26}\:\mathrm{kg}$. Specific charge is $8.04\times 10^{6} \:\mathrm{C \:kg^{-1}}$.
>
> #### Textbook 2 Example 1:
>
> A lithium nucleus contains 3 protons and 4 neutrons. It has a charge of $3\times1.60\times 10^{-19}\:\mathrm{C}$ and it has a mass of $7\times1.67\times 10^{-27}\:\mathrm{kg}$. Specific charge is $4.0\times 10^{7} \:\mathrm{C \:kg^{-1}}$.

So what is the problem?

Textbook 2 matches how I think it is done to calculate the specific charge, however when I apply that technique to magnesium ion question is first book then it doesn't work out correctly... especially the charge.

Additionally I don't understand why the charge of the magnesium ion is only 2* bigger than the charge of the hydrogen atom, although magnesium has 12 protons while the hydrogen only has 1 proton.

Comment: What is, precisely, the problem? You calculate the charge and you divide by the mass, and all the examples you give do the same. On the other hand, your T2E1 does it for the lithium nucleus, but your T1E2 does it for the specific magnesium ion $\mathrm{Mn}^{2+}$, which has 12 protons, 10 neutrons and 10 electrons, hence a total charge of $2e$. Other magnesium ions have other total charges, depending on how many electrons you strip off, and will therefore have different specific charges too. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Alright, I get that it would be an ion and have a different charge, but how does the calculated charge differ from the magnesium if it isn't an ion and how do you calculate the charge if it is an ion

Comment: If it's not an ion, then it is neutral and it has no charge. If it is an ion, then you need to specify which one, i.e. how many electrons you've taken away (or added in), and that directly specifies the charge.

Comment: I think this question is off-topic.  The difficulty is in understanding the calculation made in the textbook, not understanding any specific concept of physics.  The answer has no benefit for anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your examples look perfectly consistent with each other.

The thing to note here is that your first textbook's second example is working out the case for a magnesium *ion*, i.e. a neutral atom with a number of electrons stripped (or added in). When this is the case, it's not enough to say that it's an ion: you need to say *which* ion, i.e. how many electrons you've added or taken away, and this is exactly equivalent to specifying the charge.

In this specific example they're doing Mg<sup>2+</sup>, so it has 12 protons, 12 neutrons, and 12-2=10 electrons, for a total charge of $2e=3.2\times 10^{-19}\:\mathrm C$ as specified. Other ions will have different charges, and therefore have different specific charges. Neutral atoms, of course, have zero charge.